# Getting a list of Spark Descriptors for precompiling spark views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I'm trying to get spark precompilation to work and going through the docs, I can see this:

```
engine.BatchCompilation(targetPath, Global.AllKnownDescriptors());
```

It doesn't look like the Global.AllKnownDescriptors() is a helper method that is included with the spark dll's so I was wondering how I would go about getting a list of the `SparkViewDescriptor` classes that I need to pass in to enable batch compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The `AllKnownDescriptors()` method comes from a [MediumTrustHosting sample](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/blob/master/src/Samples/DirectUsage/MediumTrustHosting/Global.asax.cs) and the method literally just does this:

```
public static IList<SparkViewDescriptor> AllKnownDescriptors()
{
    return new[]
      {
         Desc("home.spark", "master.spark"),
         Desc("product.spark", "master.spark"),
         Desc("productlist.spark", "master.spark"),
      };
}
```

So you can see that it's just an oversimplification but the theory is that you could reflect over your code to find all types that inherit from `SparkViewDescriptor` or alternatively keep a registry of sorts manually or in an IoC Container so that you can pass them in for precompilation.